# How can I get my 16GB SD card reader to work on my ASUS A55A with Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, sd-card, asus-laptop

I have a 16 GB SD card (Lexar Platinum II 16 GB SDHC 200x) from my camera (Olympus PEN Mini E-PM1). When I plug the SD card into my computer (ASUS A55A with Windows 8), there is no response, and the SD doesn't show up in My Computer. How to I read this card?

Comment: 1. Download the driver from the ASUS [website](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&s=385&m=A55A&os=&hashedid=n/a)
2. Once downloaded, unzip and open the CardReader_ folder.
3. Then run Setup.exe as administrator. 4. The reader will now recognize the SD Card. Hooray!

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! If you've found the solution yourself, you can post it as an answer and mark as valid answer in 24 hours. This way you'll make it easier to find for other users with similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download the driver from the [ASUS website](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&s=385&m=A55A&os=&hashedid=n/a)
2. Once downloaded, unzip and open the CardReader_ folder.
3. Then run Setup.exe as administrator.
4. The reader will now recognize the SD Card. Hooray!